# DateTime.ParseExact() - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

This:

```
DateTime newTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sectionDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Throws this:

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

When `sectionDate` looks like:

```
"4/3/2017 05:22 PM"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using `ParseExact` and the exact format is `"M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt"`

Comment: Note that "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt" will work for _both_ 1-digit and  2-digit days and months, so you don't need to use two formats.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx this will be a helpful read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do one of the following:

1) Change your format string to: `"M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt"`

OR

2) Change your input to: `"04/03/2017 05:22 PM"`

OR

3) Change your code to:

```
    DateTime newTime = DateTime.Parse(sectionDate);
```

Comment: ok, so if the date were 12/12/2017, then MM/dd/yyyy would be correct?

Comment: Well, it would work, but so would `"M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt"`.  So, choose what will work for you all the time.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Read the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me

```
DateTime newTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sectionDate, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Either use above formatter  or change your `sectionDate` to `"04/03/2017 05:22 PM";`

Comment: ok, so if the date were 12/12/2017, then MM/dd/yyyy would be correct?